# is it possibble to extend output redirection in linux (>)-programm

Tags: linux, command-line

I am using a script that returns several values, I am about to write these values into a file, however, I need to add some signs and extra notation

example:

```
sh script > output 

more output

v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
```

desired:

```
sh script >(extended) output 

more output

value1: v1 notation2: v2 term3: v3 value4: v4 number5: v5
```

is it in some way possible? In my case (because of time) postprocessing is not desired.

Comment: Pipe `my_script` into something that does the extra work.  Or add an `--extended` argument to `my_script`.

Comment: Are you saying you are looking for a template, containing lines like `value1 : [v1]`, and once you've calculated `v1` being equal to `1234`, you want the line to look like `value1 : [1234]`?

Comment: @StephenNewell it is not my program, I am using it, and making some changes is not easy

Comment: @Dominique not exactly, I am using a program that parses some values from a file these values should be stored in a file with some static notation. Image the script parses names from a database and returns something like John Doe and I need to add name: John surname: Doe (is a banal example) and this should happen instantly when I use > ubuntu program

Comment: I do not understand, if you have a program `echo John Doe` then what do you want to do? So like `echo Jogn Doe | awk '{print "name: "$1" surname: "$2}'`? What is the _exact_ output your are getting and the _exact_ transformations with that output you want to do? What does it mean to "extend output" - "extend" in what way and how exactly? Does the "example" you posted is the output of a program, or a bash script with execution of a program? You want to do something along `sh script | awk '... some parsing ...' > output`?

Comment: @KamilCuk >>sh script | awk '... some parsing ...' > output - this looks exactly what I need. I am going to measure how much it slows down the runtime. Thank you!